# Email triggered send job stopped by AMPscript Decode function issue

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, triggered-send

I'm struggling a lot and not even support is being able to help me with this, hope that you can, and read any idea. I got an email with 8 different SKUs populating each one from two DEs.

The code didn't presented an issue during the email studio tests, or during our journey builder live email pointing to a test 10 users DE. The issue is that when we ran the journey to 845k users, in journey builder appeared as delivered, but never arrived, and got an email like 2 or 3 hours after the send telling me the following:

> ExactTarget.OMM.OMMInformationException: This is an informational message not an application error.
> An error occurred when attempting to create a subscriber email. The job is configured to continue when this occurs.
> Subscriber Error Threshold: -1 (No Limit)
> ClientID: 526000982
> JobID: 63985
> ListID: 937
> BatchID: 2
> SubscriberID: 23880583
> Email Address: adrianT1181__hotmail.com
> Error Code: OMM_N_SUB_EMAIL_BLD_ERR
> -->

--- inner exception 1---

> ExactTarget.OMM.InvalidScriptException: An error occurred when attempting to resolve a function call. See inner exception for detail.
> Function Call: RedirectTo(CONCAT(@Url1,'?j
> Index: 0
> TransCode Type: Text
> Content Type: Text
> Substitution Level: Subscriber
> Message Context: Send
> Error Code: OMM_SCRIPT_SYNTAX_ERR

from OMMCommon -->

--- inner exception 2---

> ExactTarget.OMM.InvalidFunctionException: The function call does not end with the required close parenthesis [)]
> Function Call: RedirectTo(CONCAT(@Url1,'?j
> Error Code: OMM_FUNC_SYNTAX_ERR

from OMMCommon

--- Stack Trace (inner exception 2) ---

> at ExactTarget.OMM.ResolvedFunction.LoadFromInternalScript()
> at ExactTarget.OMM.ResolvedFunction..ctor(JobData jobData, String text, ScriptLanguage language, LoadContentContext contentCtx, Boolean isNestedFunction, EmailValidationContext validationContext)
> at ExactTarget.OMM.ResolvedFunctionCache.GetResolvedFunction(String functionString, ScriptLanguage language, LoadContentContext loadCtx)
> at ExactTarget.OMM.Substitution.LoadSubstitutionExpression(SubstitutionBlock substitutionBlock, Int32 startIndex)

Apparently the issue spotted by the server is on this function:

```ampscript
%%=RedirectTo(CONCAT(@Url1,'#utm_campaign=','%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute1%%', '&utm_term=','%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute2%%','&utm_medium=email','&utm_source=salesforce','&utm_content=', @SKU1))=%%
```

But again, it worked ok an all the tests.

Support is already checking this, but do you guys see anything odd or something that I can do?

Here's one of the 8 code snippets that I'm using on the email:

```ampscript
%%[
  VAR @SKU1, @Url1, @Image1, @lookupVal1, @blackPrice, @redPrice, @title
  SET @lookupVal1 = AttributeValue("sku") 
  SET @lookupVal1 = "25537"
  SET @blackPrice = "289.00"
  SET @redPrice = "69.90"
  SET @SKU1 = Lookup("Full Products Catalog","sku", "sku", @lookupVal1)
  SET @Url1 = Lookup("Full Products Catalog","url", "sku", @lookupVal1) 
  SET @Image1 = Lookup("Full Products Catalog","image", "sku", @lookupVal1) 
]%%
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" role="presentation" style="min-width: 100%; " class="stylingblock-content-wrapper">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner">
        <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center">
                <a href="%%=RedirectTo(CONCAT(@Url1,'#utm_campaign=','%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute1%%', '&utm_term=','%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute2%%','&utm_medium=email','&utm_source=salesforce','&utm_content=', @SKU1))=%%" data-linkto="https://">
                  <img data-assetid="%%=v(@SKU1)=%%" src="https://image.em.invictastores.com/lib/fe2f11727364047d7c1c72/m/5/%%=v(@SKU1)=%%.jpg" alt="%%=v(@SKU1)=%%" width="100%" style="display: block; padding: 0px; text-align: center; height: auto; width: 100%; border: 0px;">
                </a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" role="presentation" style="min-width: 100%; " class="stylingblock-content-wrapper">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner" align="center" style="text-align: center;line-height: 200%;">        
        <span style="font-size:16px;color:#808080;white-space: nowrap">
          <s style="font-size:16px;color:#808080;white-space: nowrap" class="recprodBlackPrice">$%%=v(@blackPrice)=%%</s>
          <br>
        </span>
        <span style="font-size:24px;color:#e74c3c;white-space: nowrap" class="recprodRedPrice">$%%=v(@redPrice)=%%</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" role="presentation" style="min-width: 100%; " class="stylingblock-content-wrapper">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner">
        <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center">
                <a href="%%=RedirectTo(CONCAT(@Url1,'#utm_campaign=','%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute1%%', '&utm_term=','%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute2%%','&utm_medium=email','&utm_source=salesforce','&utm_content=', @SKU1))=%%" title="watch_button" alias="watch_button" conversion="true" data-linkto="https://">
                  <img data-assetid="2333" src="https://image.em.invictastores.com/lib/fe2f11727364047d7c1c72/m/1/30cc27e3-33d4-42a9-bc9d-b4a237cc9d7c.jpg" alt="" height="33" width="169" style="display: block; padding: 2px; text-align: center; height: 33px; width: 169px; border: 0px;">
                </a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks!

Omar

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue with this is the references to the `AdditionalEmailAttribute` values.  You need to check those and refer to them without the inline notation.

I'd also move the link concatenation up to the block and detect the patterns of the parameters:

```ampscript
%%[

  VAR @SKU1, @Url1, @Image1, @lookupVal1, @blackPrice, @redPrice, @title
  SET @lookupVal1 = AttributeValue("sku") 
  SET @lookupVal1 = "25537"
  SET @blackPrice = "289.00"
  SET @redPrice = "69.90"
  SET @SKU1 = Lookup("Full Products Catalog","sku", "sku", @lookupVal1)
  SET @Url1 = Lookup("Full Products Catalog","url", "sku", @lookupVal1) 
  SET @Image1 = Lookup("Full Products Catalog","image", "sku", @lookupVal1) 
  set @AEA1 = AttributeValue("__AdditionalEmailAttribute1")
  set @AEA2 = AttributeValue("__AdditionalEmailAttribute2")

  if indexof(@Url1,"?") > 0 then
      set @sku1link =  CONCAT(@Url1,'&utm_campaign=',@AEA1, '&utm_term=',@AEA2,'&utm_medium=email','&utm_source=salesforce','&utm_content=', @SKU1)
  else
      set @sku1link =  CONCAT(@Url1,'?utm_campaign=',@AEA1, '&utm_term=',@AEA2,'&utm_medium=email','&utm_source=salesforce','&utm_content=', @SKU1)
  endif

  if empty(@lookupVal) or empty(@SKU1) or empty(@Url1) or empty(@Image1) then
    raiseError("missing required values", 1)
  endif

]%%
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" role="presentation" style="min-width: 100%; " class="stylingblock-content-wrapper">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner">
        <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center">
                <a href="%%=RedirectTo(@sku1link)=%%" data-linkto="https://">
                  <img data-assetid="%%=v(@SKU1)=%%" src="https://image.em.invictastores.com/lib/fe2f11727364047d7c1c72/m/5/%%=v(@SKU1)=%%.jpg" alt="%%=v(@SKU1)=%%" width="100%" style="display: block; padding: 0px; text-align: center; height: auto; width: 100%; border: 0px;">
                </a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" role="presentation" style="min-width: 100%; " class="stylingblock-content-wrapper">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner" align="center" style="text-align: center;line-height: 200%;">        
        <span style="font-size:16px;color:#808080;white-space: nowrap">
          <s style="font-size:16px;color:#808080;white-space: nowrap" class="recprodBlackPrice">$%%=v(@blackPrice)=%%</s>
          <br>
        </span>
        <span style="font-size:24px;color:#e74c3c;white-space: nowrap" class="recprodRedPrice">$%%=v(@redPrice)=%%</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" role="presentation" style="min-width: 100%; " class="stylingblock-content-wrapper">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner">
        <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center">
                <a href="%%=RedirectTo(@sku1Link)=%%" title="watch_button" alias="watch_button" conversion="true" data-linkto="https://">
                  <img data-assetid="2333" src="https://image.em.invictastores.com/lib/fe2f11727364047d7c1c72/m/1/30cc27e3-33d4-42a9-bc9d-b4a237cc9d7c.jpg" alt="" height="33" width="169" style="display: block; padding: 2px; text-align: center; height: 33px; width: 169px; border: 0px;">
                </a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```